# Most Efficient EF Ordering for Multiple Columns in LocalDb

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, localdb

What is the most efficient way to order a LocalDb table in descending order by four columns?  I have a table that tracks a file storage hierarchy.  Four folders act like an odometer (one digit for each folder).  The table reflects this as a "storage item."  I need to find the highest number using all four folders.

Here is the code I am currently using.  I am worried that it is not efficient or accurate for a LocalDb database...

```
public StorageItem GetLastItem()
{
    var item = _context.StorageItems.AsNoTracking()
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.LevelA)           // int
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.LevelB)           // int
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.LevelC)           // int
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.ItemNumber)       // int
               .Where(x => !x.AuditDateDeleted.HasValue)   // DateTime?
               FirstOrDefault();

    // Caching logic here

     return item;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it'll be inefficient, but chaining a bunch of `OrderByDescending`s is probably not what you intended to do. Currently, this should generate a SQL `ORDER BY` clause of `ItemNumber DESC, LevelC DESC, LevelB DESC, LevelA DESC`. I think you want to use `ThenByDescending`...

```
var item = _context.StorageItems.AsNoTracking()
           .Where(x => !x.AuditDateDeleted.HasValue)
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.LevelA)        
           .ThenByDescending(x => x.LevelB)         
           .ThenByDescending(x => x.LevelC)          
           .ThenByDescending(x => x.ItemNumber)     
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Also moved the where clause higher up, although I think the database should be smart enough to optimize that.